# Type 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not have a public property named 'clientidmode'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

This code doesn't build in my website developed in *asp.net* and *c#* with *.net 4.0* using *Visual studio 2012*

code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" ClientIDMode="Static" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Mypage.aspx.cs" Inherits="info" %>
```

then i started building the page and i got this error.

```
Error parsing attribute 'clientidmode': Type 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not 
have a public property named 'clientidmode'.
```

Any thoughts on the same are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your project is not targeting the .NET 4.0 framework. You may have 4.0 installed, but please verify that the project properties indicate that you're compiling against the full .Net 4.0+ framework. You'll also want to make sure that the App Pool that the site is running under is setup for the .Net 4.0+ framework.

[image: Project Properties - Target Framework]